# How does UEFI firmware choose from multiple ESPs?

Tags: uefi, firmware

I am about to install an OS that may create its own ESP when I already have one. I am wondering which one will be actually used; will the firmware, according to the specification, choose one of them (say the first valid ESP that it finds), or maybe it will read data from both partitions and display it in boot menu?

Comment: You should only have one ESP per drive. It is ok for multiple installs to share that ESP. ESP actually uses GUID to know which partition is the ESP. Tools like gparted using boot flag are really setting the very long GUID in background. In Linux you can see GUID with `sudo efibootmgr -v` and `lsblk -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,partuuid` GUID is partUUID

Comment: @oldfred actually I have found this thread on FreeBSD forums https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/cant-boot-on-uefi.68141/ where a poster shows that they have 2 ESPs, and, quoting this article https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/ , "UEFI is a permissive spec, and if you follow the design logically, there’s really no problem with having just as many EFI system partitions as you want." But I don't quite get it what that would look like on my system. But I understand the we should have one ESP. And then what if I have multiple drives? which esp is use

Comment: I have seen where a user wanted two separate installs of Windows, so removed boot flag from first ESP and created second. Then able to boot both directly from grub. And since UEFI really uses GUID, it should find that. But some UEFI implementations only work with one ESP per drive. You just may have to test to see if your system is permissive or vendor did not implement it to allow that.

Answer (score 0):

Without a special file `BOOTX64.EFI` in folder `BOOT` on the ESP (I assume only the first ESP on a device counts here), most motherboards will not automatically detect bootloaders on the ESP at all, which means moving the drive to another device or resetting the UEFI firmware would cause it not to boot, and after starting the computer once with the device removed, the UEFI boot entry would also be normally gone.

Only one bootloader can occupy this default boot entry. Windows creates a new  `BOOTX64.EFI` in `BOOT` automatically during installation, most Linux installers don't. Run `grub-install --removable` to do it afterwards.

For normal UEFI boot entries, which are created during bootloader installation, having the bootloader on a secondary ESP, even if it's on the same drive, is not a problem. At least in my extended experience, which includes very early UEFI implementations.